# Error using cURL on the WhatsApp web

Tags: curl

I'm trying to do a cURL, getting only the header of a site:

```
curl -I https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=51988888888&text&app_absent=0
```

But I get a prompt, until pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

[image]

Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate your objective. Is it simply to use WhatsApp?

Comment: You should quote the URL `'...'` to prevent special characters like `&` from being interpreted by the shell

Comment: ... see in particular [How to skip the evaluation of ampersand in command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50898/how-to-skip-the-evaluation-of-ampersand-in-command-line)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use quotes as follows

```
curl -I "https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=51988888888&text&app_absent=0"
```

to prevent `&` being interpreted as backgrounding of some task.

Comment: OP might also find this useful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)